# Rest parameters typing

Tags: typescript, rest, typescript-generics

I have something like this:

```
interface Options {
  // ...
  f: (a: number, ...rest: any[]) => number[];
}
```

And hundreds of files using that interface, some files use it like this (contrived examples):

```
const options: Options = {
    // ...
    f(a, b) {
        console.log(b);
        return [a];
    }
}
```

And some other files use it like this:

```
const options: Options = {
    // ...
    f(a) {
        return [a];
    }
}
```

I want to modify the interface to type check the `rest` params without having to modify all the files using it.

I did some tests and I know that I can type the `rest` params of a function in the following way:

```
// Works like a charm!
function f<T extends unknown[]>(n: number, ...rest: T) {
    return [n, ...rest];
}

const a = f(1)
const b = f(1, {"c": "d"});
```

But when trying to implement it on the interface like this:

```
interface Options {
  // ...
  f: <T extends unknown[]>(a: number, ...rest: T) => number[];
}
```

I get a TS error:

```
const opt1: Options = {
    // TS Error!
    f(a, b) {
        console.log(b);
        return [a];
    }
}

const opt2: Options = {
    // TS Error!
    f(a) {
        return [a];
    }
}
```

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczIN4ChnIwBcyAPACrIQAekIAJgM7ICuIA1iAPYDuIA2gF0AfAAo4JECwC2AI2gAaZADpVUCIzAlyASmQBeYcilzoQgNy4AvrlsIuITci6YAjCQxZ9OfAULilWT08P1Dke0cuABsIZSiuAHNRIMswv3UwFigQZH44QVS-GxtcCKcXMAAmD0wDH1CYcWDfNIysnLyCluRiuwcnKFc6itdlRtclbAAiOCmSKdkpqx1LMqwoSuHMSrHRVxWgA) with the above example and the errors, which I haven't figure out how to solve.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Try `f: <T extends unknown>(a: number, ...rest: T[]) => number[];`. See [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4y6vw) . If it works I can wrap it into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variation on your interface should resolve the compiler errors, and allow you to leave your other code as-is:

```ts
interface Opt<T extends unknown[] = unknown[]> {
  f: (a: number, ...rest: T) => number[];
}
```

[Your playground code, updated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAcwB4AqyIAekIAJgM7ICuIA1iAPYDuIA2gLrIC8VtDz7APmQBvAFDJkMAFzIAFHBkhKAWwBG0ADTIAdLqgQyYGTgCUXIUrXR2AblEBfUU4T0Qh5PUwBGGRjBcRcQlJeS1VMzFgqOQXN3oAGwhtePoAc1lwu2jg-TBKKBBkFjg2LODHR1FY908wACZfTADI4Jh5CKDs3PzC4tLO5ArnV3coLwDar202ry1hACI4eZl51Xn7Eztq-yg6icw66dkvTacAejOPTGBXOHj4gE9kdCh6ADdgEhRUiBBoYAQyDgUFSKl+-jA9HwIBg9CgSGewLgyggkCgyDAD3QECqI38tQAzI1sCxDFBQKk2EJuC0JG04GEOtkJNUEkkUulMgMot0CkUSmUJENcW4dgSAIL7MAEo4nGzIC7IBj+X70SipAAWQJBYPAZBFowJACEpTKZnNFstkKt1psFZdGK8QKkMVicdtkFACQBhU2yrTzDUQe5Qxhw+IkeZ2xX0GiiIA)